# How can I receive keyboard input in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, input, nsview

I currently trying to create my own custom cocoa library for C to create a window. The only thing that is missing is getting input from the user and display it through NSText / NSView. I have looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextinputcontext?language=objc) but it has not helped me in any way to create an input box. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating an Appkit replacement or a C wrapper around Appkit clases? Is `NSTextView` what you're looking for?

Comment: Something similar to NSTextView is what I am aiming for.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [TextInputView Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TextInputView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008840)

Comment: If you want to process the input yourself, implement `- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event` in your `NSView` subclass.